# Code Access Security and Sharepoint WebParts

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts, code-access-security

I've got a vague handle on how Code Access Security works in Sharepoint.

I have developed a custom webpart and setup a CAS policy in my Manifest

```
<CodeAccessSecurity>
<PolicyItem>
  <PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Description="Permission set for Okana">
    <IPermission class="Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" version="1" ObjectModel="True" Impersonate="True" />
    <IPermission class="SecurityPermission" version="1" Flags="Assertion, Execution, ControlThread, ControlPrincipal, RemotingConfiguration" />
    <IPermission class="AspNetHostingPermission" version="1" Level="Medium" />
    <IPermission class="DnsPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
    <IPermission class="EventLogPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true">
      <Machine name="localhost" access="Administer" />
    </IPermission>
    <IPermission class="EnvironmentPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
    <IPermission class="System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/>
    <IPermission class="System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
    <IPermission class="System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
    <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" PathDiscovery="*AllFiles*" />
    <IPermission class="IsolatedStorageFilePermission" version="1" Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser" UserQuota="9223372036854775807" />
    <IPermission class="PrintingPermission" version="1" Level="DefaultPrinting" />
    <IPermission class="PerformanceCounterPermission" version="1">
      <Machine name="localhost">
        <Category name="Enterprise Library Caching Counters" access="Write"/>
        <Category name="Enterprise Library Cryptography Counters" access="Write"/>
        <Category name="Enterprise Library Data Counters" access="Write"/>
        <Category name="Enterprise Library Exception Handling Counters" access="Write"/>
        <Category name="Enterprise Library Logging Counters" access="Write"/>
        <Category name="Enterprise Library Security Counters" access="Write"/>
      </Machine>
    </IPermission>
    <IPermission class="ReflectionPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/>
    <IPermission class="SecurityPermission" version="1" Flags="SerializationFormatter, UnmanagedCode, Infrastructure, Assertion, Execution, ControlThread, ControlPrincipal, RemotingConfiguration, ControlAppDomain,ControlDomainPolicy"  />
    <IPermission class="SharePointPermission" version="1" ObjectModel="True" />
    <IPermission class="SmtpPermission" version="1" Access="Connect" />
    <IPermission class="SqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/>
    <IPermission class="WebPartPermission" version="1" Connections="True" />
    <IPermission class="WebPermission" version="1">
      <ConnectAccess>
        <URI uri="$OriginHost$"/>
      </ConnectAccess>
    </IPermission>
  </PermissionSet>
  <Assemblies>
     ....
  </Assemblies>
```

This is correctly converted into a **wss_custom_wss_minimaltrust.config** when it is deployed onto the Sharepoint server and mostly works.

To get the WebPart working fully, however I find that I need to modify the **wss_custom_wss_minimaltrust.config** by hand after deployment and set Unrestricted="true" on the permissions set

```
 <PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Description="Permission set for MyApp" Name="mywebparts.wsp-86d8cae1-7db2-4057-8c17-dc551adb17a2-1">
```

to

```
<PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Description="Permission set for MyApp" Name="mywebparts.wsp-86d8cae1-7db2-4057-8c17-dc551adb17a2-1" Unrestricted="true">
```

It's all because I'm loading a User Control from the webpart. I don't believe there is a way to enable that using CAS but am willing to be proven wrong.

Is there a way to set something in the manifest so I don't need to make this fix by hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your web part in the bin file?

Have you set partially trusted callers in the assembly?

If not do so! it's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is hard to determine what permissions are actually being used when loading a usercontrol.  Try granting unrestricted=true on the following list of security classes, and if you get it working, remove them one by one until you get the minimal set needed for your web part:

```
            <SecurityClass Name="AllMembershipCondition" Description="System.Security.Policy.AllMembershipCondition, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="AspNetHostingPermission" Description="System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <SecurityClass Name="DataProtectionPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.DataProtectionPermission, System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="DnsPermission" Description="System.Net.DnsPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="EnvironmentPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="EventLogPermission" Description="System.Diagnostics.EventLogPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="FileCodeGroup" Description="System.Security.Policy.FileCodeGroup, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="FileDialogPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="FileIOPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="FirstMatchCodeGroup" Description="System.Security.Policy.FirstMatchCodeGroup, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <SecurityClass Name="IsolatedStorageFilePermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="KeyContainerPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="NamedPermissionSet" Description="System.Security.NamedPermissionSet"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="NetCodeGroup" Description="System.Security.Policy.NetCodeGroup, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="OleDbPermission" Description="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="PerformanceCounterPermission" Description="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="PrintingPermission" Description="System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="ReflectionPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="RegistryPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="SecurityPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="SocketPermission" Description="System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="SharePointPermission" Description="Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            <SecurityClass Name="SmtpPermission" Description="System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <SecurityClass Name="SqlClientPermission" Description="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="StorePermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.StorePermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="StrongNameMembershipCondition" Description="System.Security.Policy.StrongNameMembershipCondition, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="UIPermission" Description="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="UnionCodeGroup" Description="System.Security.Policy.UnionCodeGroup, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="UrlMembershipCondition" Description="System.Security.Policy.UrlMembershipCondition, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <SecurityClass Name="WebPartPermission" Description="Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.WebPartPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            <SecurityClass Name="WebPermission" Description="System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <SecurityClass Name="ZoneMembershipCondition" Description="System.Security.Policy.ZoneMembershipCondition, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To setup cas look at the codeplex and see wspbuilder.

You won't need to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there is no way you can apply custom cas for user controls. Dlls loading user controls should necessarily be in Gac or the web application Trust level need to be set to full.
Try avoiding user control if you need to put your dll in bin